# A query to get entities based on matching IDs in the index method

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I believe this should be a relatively easy question where I am missing something obvious. I'm trying to populate an `IEnumerable` object from my viewmodel with the collection from another object.

```
public class PostIndexData
{
    public IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public Animal Animal { get; set; }
    public Species Species { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Breed> Breeds {get;set;}
}
```

I'm trying to access the `AnimalID` from my class `Animal` and compare that to the `AnimalID` in my class `Breed` using this query in my index method in a controller:

```
    public  IActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        var viewModel = new PostIndexData();
        viewModel.Posts = _context.Post
            .Include(i => i.Address)
            .Include(i => i.Animal)
            .Include(i => i.Animal.Species);

        //viewModel.Breeds = _context.Breed;
        if (id != null)
        {
            ViewBag.PostID = id.Value;
            viewModel.Animal = viewModel.Posts.Where(i => i.PostID == id.Value).Single().Animal;
            viewModel.Breeds = from s in _context.Breed.Where(i => i.AnimalID == viewModel.Animal.AnimalID) select s;
            viewModel.Address = viewModel.Posts.Where(i => i.PostID == id.Value).Single().Address;
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

This query is returning all of the entries in `Breed` and not the corresponding Breed(s) with the current `Animal` based on `AnimalID`. Does anyone know of a better way to handle this or possible resources? Thanks

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male, Female
}

public class Animal
{
    //public Animal()
    //{
    //    this.Breeds = new HashSet<Breed>();
    //}
    [Required]
    public string AnimalName { get; set; }
    public int AnimalID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public int SpeciesID { get; set; }
    public Species Species { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Breed> Breeds { get; set; }
}
```

It has an `ICollection` of `Breed`s as a navigation property (there can be zero to many breeds listed).

My `Breeds` class is as follows:

```
public class Breed
{
    public int BreedID { get; set; }
    public int AnimalID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Breed cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    public string BreedName { get; set; }

    public Animal Animal { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just `.Include(i => i.Animal.Breeds)` on your initial fetch and then `viewModel.Breeds = viewModel.Posts.Single(i => i.PostID == id.Value).Animal.Breeds` ?  [You can put your where clause inside Single()]

Answer (score 0):

Actually this seems to be working now without any changes. I simply exited out of Visual Studio and reopened it. It's been a little annoying with some changes not taking effect after a rebuild. Not sure of whether to leave this up or delete since it might not be that useful...

Comment: Fix your build settings. For example it might be set so it only builds the startup project, etc.